# Group Shapes by Shape Object in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I'm having problems in grouping shapes by name with VBA in Excel.
This happens because I have multiple shapes that can have the same name.

The following code can recreate my problem.
You can uncomment line `OriginalShape.Name = "MyShape"` to see the error.

```vb
Sub test()
    
    ' Create Original Shape
    Dim OriginalShape As Shape
    Set OriginalShape = Sheet1.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 5, 20, 50, 50)
    
    ' Rename Shape to simulate my project
'    OriginalShape.Name = "MyShape" ' Uncomment line to recreate problem
    
    ' Copy and Paste Shape (I believe there is no other way to do this)
    OriginalShape.Copy
    Sheet1.Paste Sheet1.Range("C2")
    
    ' Get Object of Last Pasted Shape
    Dim CloneShape As Shape
    Set CloneShape = Sheet1.Shapes(Sheet1.Shapes.Count)
    
    ' Group Shapes
    Dim ShapeGroup As Shape
    Set ShapeGroup = Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array(OriginalShape.Name, CloneShape.Name)).Group

End Sub
```

I know I also have the possibility to use Shape indexes, like `Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array(1, 2)).Group`, but this is doesn't seem a good way either, as I would need to store one more variable for each shape (the shape index) apart from the shape Object.

Is there a way to group shapes some other way, like through Object or ID.
I believe the best would be something like.

```
Set ShapeGroup = Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array(OriginalShape, CloneShape)).Group
'OR
Set ShapeGroup = Sheet1.Shapes.Range(Array(OriginalShape.ID, CloneShape.ID)).Group
```

Comment: If shapes have the same name, how does your code know which ones need to be grouped?  Or you just want to group all shapes on the sheet, or ?  Your test code doesn't tell us much about what you actually need to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Tim Williams said: the code fails, as the group-array consists of equal names. What you need to do, is adding the index to the name while creating the shapes

This will work:

```vb
Sub test()
    
   
    Const cntShapes As Long = 2
    
    
    Dim i As Long, shp As Shape, cTarget As Range
    Dim arrShapeNames(1 To cntShapes) As Variant
    
    With Sheet1
        For i = 1 To cntShapes
            Set cTarget = .Cells(1, i)   'adjust this to your needs
            Set shp = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, cTarget.Left, cTarget.Top, 50, 50)
            shp.Name = "MyShape." & i   'adding the index to the name makes it unique
            arrShapeNames(i) = shp.Name
        Next
    End With
    
    
    ' Group Shapes
    Dim ShapeGroup As Shape
    Set ShapeGroup = Sheet1.Shapes.Range(arrShapeNames).Group

End Sub
```

Comment: This idea is great. I would improve it to ```shp.Name = shp.Name & shp.ID```. This way, it will handle better if some shapes are deleted.

Comment: Sorry - I don't see an issue using i-index - but it is possible to append the shape ID as well. If this answer is a good solution to your question it would be nice if you select it as "answer" - thanks